# How to disable the right-click loop

Tags: html

i want to hide the right-click list when on a video, really concerning the loop

already tried Loop  {display:none !important; }

----it still shows up when i right-click on a video

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by placing one overlay div over video with CSS

like this :

```
video{
position: relative;
}
#overelay{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
top:0px;
}
```

this will work. :)

Comment: I put it in exactly as written in chrome.ccs and it doesnt work  for this website https://classic.motown.com or https://playback.fm

Comment: this is what i want to disable when i right-click a video= loop